# Separate the hue tag into a new tag for questions specifically about Philips Hue

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

We're the developers of the [Philips Hue](http://meethue.com) API and would like to start using Stack Overflow to answer questions pertaining to our API. It looks like there is already [a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hue) in place for this on Stack Overflow.

However, many questions that have been tagged [hue](/questions/tagged/hue) appear to be unrelated to the actual Philips product. That's probably because the word 'hue' is so generic (and why the product is located at http://meethue.com and not http://hue.com).

Rather than going in and editing questions that are actually about hue, the property of a color, it would probably make more sense to separate questions about Philips Hue into a new tag, something like [philips-hue](/questions/tagged/philips-hue) and leave questions about other forms of hue with their current tag.

Is this something that makes sense? I would go ahead and start doing it but I just wanted to doublecheck with moderation and other members here to see what you guys think is the best direction to take.

Comment: I might note that I can't actually *find* any current questions about our API using this tag, so I'm not sure why the tag wiki specifies Philips Hue when it doesn't actually appear to be about Philips Hue at all. But our intent is to forward developers in the future to SO for help. ;-)

Comment: Perhaps we should separate out the Philips Hue tag from the traditional Hue tag by colouring one in a particular 'hue'.

Comment: Let's not cry about a hue.

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and removed the tag wiki summary that incorrectly assigns Philips Hue as the subject of the tag when in fact none of the questions are about Philips Hue at all. Since I don't yet have tag wiki privileges here, someone will have to take a look at it in the queue.

And then later when we do start forwarding questions here, we'll make sure to create our own tag and not add to this mess. ;-)

Comment: For what it's worth, it _is_ a mess. It's not just questions about color hue.